# "502 Bad Gateway" error occurs at my Elastic Beanstalk server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, nestjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Elastic Beanstalk server that runs a Nest.js application.

The workload of this server is not high: The average CPU utilitization is under one percent.

Interestingly the server returns 502 Gateway error sometimes.

After I deployed a new version with CodePipeline, everything works perfect in the first 10 minutes. After 10 minutes, it started returning 502 Bad Gateway error. The interesting part is that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

When I checked log file at AWS console, I see "connection refused" error in everywhere.

These are the things that I did to prevent this issue:

- I set 8081 as PORT in my "Environment Variables" section.
- I renamed main.js to app.js.

Any recommendations or solutions?

It problem happens in my production server. I have to fix it ASAP.